# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client NODEJS MONGOOSE

Tags: node.js, rest, mongoose

i have these post on express with nodejs but it throws this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

these error was catched by the try/catch of the newProducto.save() but i dont understand what is happening

```
route.post('/post/subiruno', (req, res) => {
    ProductoModel.findOne({
        nombre: req.body.nombre
    }).then(
        (producto) => {
            if (producto) {
                console.log(`El producto ${req.body.nombre} ya existe`)
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: `El producto ${req.body.nombre} ya existe`
                })
            } else {
                let newProducto = new ProductoModel({
                    nombre: req.body.nombre,
                    marca: req.body.marca,
                    cantidad: req.body.cantidad,
                    distribuidor: req.body.distribuidor,
                    unidad_De_Empaque: req.body.unidad_De_Empaque,
                    valor_Unidad_De_Empaque: req.body.valor_Unidad_De_Empaque,
                    valor_Unitario: req.body.valor_Unitario,
                    distribuidor_2: req.body.distribuidor,
                    unidad_De_Empaque_2: req.body.unidad_De_Empaque,
                    valor_Unidad_De_Empaque_2: req.body.valor_Unidad_De_Empaque,
                    valor_Unitario_2: req.body.valor_Unitario,
                    distribuidor_3: req.body.distribuidor,
                    unidad_De_Empaque_3: req.body.unidad_De_Empaque,
                    valor_Unidad_De_Empaque_3: req.body.valor_Unidad_De_Empaque,
                    valor_Unitario_3: req.body.valor_Unitario,
                    categoria: req.body.categoria,
                    subCategorias: req.body.subCategoria
                })

                newProducto.save()
                    .then(
                        res.json(newProducto)
                    ).catch(err => {
                        res.json(err)
                    })
            }
        }
    )
})
```

Comment: For starters, this `.then(res.json(newProducto))` needs to be `.then(() => { res.json(newProductor })`

Answer (score 0):

As said, @jfriend00 the mistake was on the .then
This is the code corrected.
A big hug people!

```
route.post('/post/subiruno', (req, res) => {
    ProductoModel.findOne({
        nombre: req.body.nombre
    }).then(
        (producto) => {
            if (producto) {
                console.log(`El producto ${req.body.nombre} ya existe`)
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: `El producto ${req.body.nombre} ya existe`
                })
            } else {

                const generadorDeCodigo = (categoria) => {
                    const tipo = categoria;
                    const tipoSliced = tipo.slice(0, 3);
                    var codigo = `${tipoSliced}`;
                    return codigo
                }

                let newProducto = new ProductoModel({
                    nombre: req.body.nombre,
                    marca: req.body.marca,
                    cantidad: req.body.cantidad,
                    distribuidor: req.body.distribuidor,
                    unidad_De_Empaque: req.body.unidad_De_Empaque,
                    valor_Unidad_De_Empaque: req.body.valor_Unidad_De_Empaque,
                    valor_Unitario: req.body.valor_Unitario,
                    distribuidor_2: req.body.distribuidor,
                    unidad_De_Empaque_2: req.body.unidad_De_Empaque,
                    valor_Unidad_De_Empaque_2: req.body.valor_Unidad_De_Empaque,
                    valor_Unitario_2: req.body.valor_Unitario,
                    distribuidor_3: req.body.distribuidor,
                    unidad_De_Empaque_3: req.body.unidad_De_Empaque,
                    valor_Unidad_De_Empaque_3: req.body.valor_Unidad_De_Empaque,
                    valor_Unitario_3: req.body.valor_Unitario,
                    categoria: req.body.categoria,
                    subCategorias: req.body.subCategoria,
                    codigoDeProducto: generadorDeCodigo(req.body.categoria)
                })

                newProducto.save()
                    .then(() => {
                        res.json(newProducto)
                    }
                    ).catch(err => {
                        res.json(err)
                    })
            }
        }
    )
})
```